# Quais as Dlls Preciso para criar um projeto com oracle no visual studio 2015?

Tags: asp.net

Ola pessoa tudo bem? atualmente estou tentando criar um novo projeto no visual studio 2015 com a nova versão do oracle RC1 update 2 eu gostaria de saber quais as Dlls do devart preciso para configurar meu projeto para criar conexão com o banco e tudo mais...
desde ja agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não mencionou se deseja trabalhar com ADO.NET ou Entity Framework.
Em todo caso, aconselho que trabalhe com `EF6 Code First`, para tal basta instalar o seguinte `NuGet`:

[Official Oracle ODP.NET, Managed... 12.1.2400](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework/)

Se preferir, pode faze-lo por linha de comando: `PM> Install-Package Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework`

Ele já tem como dependência o `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` (Caso queira trabalhar com ADO.NET) e o `EntityFramework`.

lembrando que não deve utilizar o EF7 para trabalhar com Oracle, o mesmo ainda não tem suporte para o Oracle.

Lembrando que o `Visual Studio` permite criar o seu Modelo `Code First` de forma "automatizada", para tal adicione um item ao seu projeto `ADO.NET Entity Data Model`, então escolha `Code First from Database`.

Caso não tenha esta opção, talvez seja necessario instalar o [Entity Framework 6 Tools for Visual Studio 2012 & 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762), mas como está à utilizar o VS 2015, acredito que não seja necessario.

Comment: Eu não entendi muito bem, pois sou iniciante TobyMosque, porem vou fazer o meu projetinho de estudos em query acredito que seja o ADO.NET que você esta falando.

Comment: @MarceloLopes, ADO.NET é a tecnologia que você usa para acessar qual quer banco de Dados, através dele você define objetos de conexão, comandos sql, leitura e modificação dos dados... Na internet você entra varios tutorias de como utilizar ele para acessar um Banco SqlServer, usando classes como SqlConnection, SqlCommand, SqlDataReader, tentre outras... Para Oracle você terá de instalar o `Oracle.ManagedDataAcess` (a forma mais simples é pelo `NuGet`), então utilize as classes OracleConnection, OracleCommand, OracleDataReader.

Comment: ja estou fazendo um projetinho com isso pra estudar obrigado.

Comment: @MarceloLopes, se aparecer qual quer duvida pelo caminho, é só fazer uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Ta certo obrigado